# Can't Scroll Canvas Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a frame (class page1) to fill with labels for each row of a csv. If there are too many rows I would like the users to be able to scroll to see them all.

The app starts on a frame that doesn't need a scroll bar (`class StartPage`)

```py
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both", expand = True)
        self.frames = {}

        page_list = [StartPage,page1]
        for F in page_list:
            frame = F(container, self, *args)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height = 700,width = 800)
        canvas.pack()

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage (tk.Frame):

    def __init__ (self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="visit page1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(page1))
        button.pack()

class page1 (tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, height = 700,width = 800)
        canvas.pack()

        csv = pd.read_csv('guitest_sheet/pd_guitest.csv', engine='python')
        csv_df = pd.DataFrame(csv)
        count = 0
        relx = .5
        height = 45
        for row in csv.iterrows() : 
            frame_name = "frame" + str(count)
            frame_name = tk.Frame(canvas, bg="black", bd=5)
            frame_name.place(width=400, height=height, relx=relx, y=((count+1)*height)+10,anchor='center')
            for x in row :
                if type(x) != int: 
                    label = tk.Label(frame_name, text="label")
                    label.place(width=100, anchor="n",relx=.5, rely=0)
            count+=1

        scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(parent, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
        scroll_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

        scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(parent, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set, xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set,scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code and error message

Comment: what is the problem ? Do you get error? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: No error message. scroll bar is just grey

Comment: `pd.read_csv()` gives data frame - you don't need to use `DataFrame(csv)`

Comment: thanks but that's not what I'm asking for help with

Comment: it is place for comments - here we can suggest other changes, not only solutions for you question.

Comment: the main problem is that to put item on canvas you have to use `canvas.create_window(Widget)`, not `place()/pack()/grid()`. You can only put `Frame` on canvas `canvas.create_window(Frame)` and then you can add element to this Frame using `place()/pack()/grid()`

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me but after all changes I don't rember what I have changed.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        page_list = [StartPage, Page1]
        for F in page_list:
            frame = F(container, self, *args)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="news")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)


    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage (tk.Frame):

    def __init__ (self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        button = tk.Button(self, text="visit page1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button.pack()

class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

        scroll_x = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        scroll_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

        scroll_y = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set)

        inner_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=inner_frame, anchor='nw')

        csv = pd.read_csv('test.csv', engine='python')
        for row in csv.iterrows() : 
            frame_name = tk.Frame(inner_frame)
            frame_name.pack()

            for x in row:
                if not isinstance(x, int): 
                    label = tk.Label(frame_name, text="label")
                    label.pack()

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))


app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Is it possible to do this using "place" for the "frame_name" frames? I just get a grey screen right now.

Comment: frankly: I don't know. I never use `place`. I don't like `place` because it doesn't resize elements when I resize window - and I like to resize window to full screen to see more elements. With `place` I would have to calculate `x, y`, with `pack` I don't have to. And I can use `padx`, `pady` to make the same distance between elements. On different systems the same element may need different values `x,y` in `place`, with `pack` I don't have this problem.